# how to return a FileResult from a string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I need to write an action that will return a FileResult from a string

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the `FileContentResult` class.

```
        var contentType = "text/xml";
        var content = "<content>Your content</content>";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var result = new FileContentResult(bytes, contentType);
        result.FileDownloadName = "myfile.xml";
        return result;
```